# _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

Below is my code, just trying to include a decorator but getting the above error, have used the decorator elsewhere with no issues.

```
class AudienceListView(ListView):
    model = Audience
    template_name = 'audience/list.html'

    @method_decorator(company_user_has_permission('audiences_view'))
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        company = Company.get_current(self.request)
        return queryset.filter(company=company) \
            .annotate(total_deals=Count("deals"), total_contacts=Count("contacts")) \
            .order_by('-id')
```

edit: Now working.

Comment: Hi, what does the error say? Please paste the error log, it can be helpful in figuring out what is wrong

Comment: Now working and added fix to question.

Answer (score 0):

function `company_user_has_permission` needed `request`, which you don't have in `get_queryset` call.

you have an error here `company_user_has_permission` not in get_queryset.

Comment: tried amending to def get_queryset(self, request): with the same result.

Comment: view.get_queryset() dont take any request. that's why you are not successfull. Can you supply  us with code of "company_user_has_permission" ?

Comment: Managed to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed, needed to use the decorator above the class and set the 'name' parameter to 'dispatch':

```
@method_decorator(company_user_has_permission('audiences_view'), name='dispatch')
```